# Proof of Concept Ethereum

Tags: proof-of-stake

i knew about proof of Work and proof of Stake in term of Ethereum. But recently i heard something about proof of concept in Ethereum.

Can anyone explain what it means by proof of concept? How does it different with PoW and PoS?
Or does Proof of Concept really exists in the first place?

Answer (score 7):

Proof of Concept (PoC) has nothing to do with consensus algorithms (PoW, PoS) or Ethereum specifically.

PoC is basically a prototype application built with the purpose to verify that certain concepts or theories have the potential for real-world application.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept